# change characher to date column in r list

Tags: r

I have an R list of data frames called timeSeries. Each data frame has two columns, one with a character-format date and the other is a numerical value (a price). I want to loop through the list and change the character-format column to a date format. Code:

```
> lapply(timeSeries,function(x) (data.frame(as.Date(x[,1]),x[,2])))
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , 2) : undefined columns selected
>
```

But apply the function on each element in the list and it works:

```
> f1<-function(x) (data.frame(as.Date(x[,1]),x[,2]))
> timeSeries$AA<-f1(timeSeries$AA)
>
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try using `lapply` with your custom function `f1` on EVERY data frame in the `timeSeries` list?

Comment: Thanks! I made a fix in syntax and removed the call to return

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea to use `lapply`:

```
# returns input data frame x with first column converted to date
df_to_date <- function(x) {
    x[1] <- as.Date(x[1], format="%d/%m/%Y")
    return x
}

timeSeries <- lapply(timeSeries, function(x) df_to_date(x))
```